# Connect to (virtual) network adapter on other computer via domain LAN

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, domain, tunnel

I have a virtual linux machine (192.168.0.100) running on a Windows 10 Test PC. This exposes a (virtual) network adapter (192.168.0.99). From my Windows 10 development PC (IP-Address a.b.c.d), I would like to connect to the virtual machine on the Test PC in the same domain network (IP-Address a.b.c.t). I can reach the Test PC via Remote Desktop, but obviously not directly the virtual network adapter.

What are my options (tunneling, vpn) and how should I configure it, preferredly with Windows tools? Windows version is 1809.

Comment: in your VM configuration, what type of network connection do you have? many common systems have a type called "bridged" that allows the vnic too operate on the lan directly with its own IP. set the guest network connection to a static IP if you want, or use DHCP (perhaps with a reservation).

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you using to do the virtualization?

Usually there's stuff you can do depending on whether its VMWare, Virtualbox, or whatever to be able to connect as you please, but very generally speaking all you would need to do is bridge the physical adapter with the virtual adapter on the host machine.

Your original post is a little confusing though - Out of 192.168.0.99 & 192.168.0.100, which is the virtual machine and which is the host? And the development PC is a 3rd machine which is also 192.168.0.x?

Comment: The virtual machine is a proprietary RTOS from acontis. It exposes a network adapter to the windows host, which I assigned the address 192.168.0.99. I can ping the virtual machine with the address 192.168.0.100. The domain network has a totally different IP range, where I have no influence on.

Comment: Oh so the development machine is some other ip range, and the host machine has an IP which is in that range, *and* another network adapter which is in 192.168.0.x, right? If that's the case, then let's say for now that this other network is 10.0.0.0/24, and your development machine is 10.0.0.100, and the host machine is 10.0.0.200. All you should need to do is add a static route on the development machine saying `192.168.0.0/24 via 10.0.0.200` (I'm assuming the mask for 192.168.0.x is /24). You may also need to allow the traffic you need through Windows firewall on the host as well.